# HttpURLConnection FileNotFoundException with Response Code 200

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, twitch

I'm trying to retrieve some videos with a GameId from Helix API of Twitch. Using a REST client I can retrieve the data and it works, but when I try it on android it won't work.
I get a response code 200, but when I try to access the InputStream I get a FileNotFoundException.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Client-ID", Configuration.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        System.out.println("ResponseCode: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();

        String jsonString = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);

        return new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Where `Configuration.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID` is my Twitch Client ID. 
The output I get is:

```
01-16 02:19:19.658 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow I/System.out: ResponseCode: 200
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.twitch.tv/helix/videos?game_id=9435
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at ec.com.aurinow.aurinow.TwitchSearchActivity$RetrieveResponseTask.sendRequest(TwitchSearchActivity.java:272)
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at ec.com.aurinow.aurinow.TwitchSearchActivity$RetrieveResponseTask.doInBackground(TwitchSearchActivity.java:233)
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at ec.com.aurinow.aurinow.TwitchSearchActivity$RetrieveResponseTask.doInBackground(TwitchSearchActivity.java:229)
01-16 02:19:20.133 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
01-16 02:19:20.134 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-16 02:19:20.134 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
01-16 02:19:20.134 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
01-16 02:19:20.134 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
01-16 02:19:20.134 21184-21242/ec.com.aurinow.aurinow W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thank You Guys

EDIT: So I make it work using `urlConnection.getInputStream()` instead of `url.openStream()`. I don't why in this specific case it works like that.

Comment: Try `urlConnection.getInputStream()` instead of `url.openStream()`

Comment: @Barns Yes, I just edited the question saying I did that. I don't know why url.openStream() won't work though. Thanks

Comment: So with  `urlConnection.getInputStream()` it now works?

Comment: Yes it works with `urlConnection.getInputStream()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the response from the `HttpURLConnection` object. That is where the response will be.

The `URL` object is as the documentation puts it:

> Class URL represents a Uniform Resource Locator, a pointer to a
>   "resource" on the World Wide Web.

So the `URL` only points to the resource you wish to retrieve from. The `HttpURLConnection` object is what actually contains the response after being pointed to the resource.

The `HttpURLConnection` object:

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but
>   the underlying network connection to the HTTP server...

So do this instead: 
`(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));`

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
URL url = new URL(urlString);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Client-ID", Configuration.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();

System.out.println("ResponseCode: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
br.close();

String jsonString = sb.toString();
System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);

return new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: This is what made it work, but I still have the doubt why sometimes `url.openStream()` would work, and sometimes it won't.